# How to format a number string in TCL

Tags: tcl

Hi i have a number string which out puts as a 4 digit number ie. 2850 i'd like to make that number display as 2.8 please. Ive tried various %.1f etc here's what I have so far

```
set number 2850
puts [format "%01.1f" $number]
```

which outputs incorrectly as 2.0 could you please point me in the right direction.

Thankyou to Schelte Bron for his reply is it possible to combine the format and expression into one line of code please ?

```
set number 2850
set number1 [expr {double($number) / 1000}]
set number2 [format "%01.1f" $number1]
puts "$number2
```

so instead we would have something like

```
set number 2850
set number1 [expr {double($size) / 1000} -format "%01.1f $number]
puts $number1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess your description misses the part where you do `[expr {$number / 1000}]`. But you need `[expr {$number / 1000.}]` (note the . behind the 1000). Or clearer: `[expr {double($number) / 1000}]`

Comment: Explanation: `[expr {$number / 1000}]` does integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line of code, but the responsibilities of `format` and `expr` remain what they are:

```
set number2 [format "%01.1f" [expr {$number / 1000.0}]]
```

Comment: We often split things up with intermediate variables when giving explanations here, just so that people working interactively can see what each step does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to divide 2850 by 1000, it's not clear if you really want to round up to 2.9, or you want to round down to 2.8. Using format will round it up to 2.9 e.g.

```
set number [expr {2850 / 1000.0}]
puts [format "%.1f" $number]
```

Using floor will round it down to 2.8 e.g.

```
set number [expr {2850 / 100.0}]
puts [expr {floor($number) /10.0} ]
```